# flutter build web doesn't create flutter.js

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I recently made a flutter application and now I want to get a web release, but when I run `flutter build web` and upload stored files in `{root}/build/web` on the host, everything is showing on chrome and firefox with that URL is an empty page with 2 console errors:
`_flutter is not defined`
`GET https://web.pushers.ir/flutter.js 404`
I took a look at my released files and didn't see any file named flutter.js, I tried `flutter build web` many times but nothing, also I tried to create another flutter project as a sample and ran `flutter web build`, on that sample everything was ok and `flutter.js` created with other released files
What should I do?

- notice: it's working with Microsoft Edge, even while there is no file named flutter.js

Comment: Where are you deploying the app? I mean, is it AWS, Azure, Google Cloud? Also, do you get any kind of console error output?

Comment: @lepsch 
**with 2 console errors: _flutter is not defined & GET https://web.pushers.ir/flutter.js 404**
deploying on a windows server with Plesk control panel

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Had the same issue.

Long story short: run `flutter clean` instead of manually deleting the */build/web* folder or its content. The next build that follows will properly generate all files, including *flutter.js*.

[More info why that is happening](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/104830)

Answer (score 0):

I just copied flutter.js from a sample project release into my app release and it works